# background image not showing inline codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter,i am working in home.php file(in view folder),I have images folder in root (inside assets folder),but image is not displaying in front end,

I am tried with following code but not working,where i am wrong ?

```
<section id="landing" class="bg-cover centered-area clr-white" style="background-image: url('../../assets/images/bg1.jpg')">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`base_url()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) if you are using CI framework like:

```
<section id="landing" class="bg-cover centered-area clr-white" style="background-image: url('<?=base_url()?>assets/images/bg1.jpg')">
```

Or, simple, pass your path in `base_url()` method like:

```
echo base_url("assets/images/bg1.jpg");
```

The above example would return something like:

```
http://yoursite.com/assets/images/bg1.jpg
```

[**Important:**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) but make sure you have included `url` helper either in your controller class or in `autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than code like this `url('../../assets/images/bg1.jpg'` it better to use `base_url()`

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/bg1.jpg'); ?>" />
```